# Assign raster values based on polygon intersection

Tags: raster, r, intersection

I have a raster where every cell is a 1. I also have a polygon of buffer areas that fall within the raster. I want to assign all raster cells that intersect the polygon geometrics to NA. But the two files have different extents and origins. I don't see a reason to share code, since I build the raster and polygons based on proprietary data. But I can illustrate it. The black grid represents my current raster, the blue cicle is the polygon:

[image: Overlaid raster and grid]

What function will allow me to reassign the raster value of all cells that intersect the polygon? The raster would become as follows:

[image]

Comment: Though you cannot provide the proprietary data, there is still reason to provide a minimal reproducible example. As things currently stand, your question cannot be answered properly because there are many different ways of storing rasters and polygons in R. I may have a way of doing it for certain data structures, but I'm unsure if it would be at all helpful for your case. Could you provide more information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may as well use the function `mask`; according to the function help: "You can use `inverse=TRUE` to set the cells that are not `NA` (or other maskvalue) in the mask"

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
m = matrix(rep(1,100), ncol = 10)
r = raster(m)

point = st_sfc(st_point(c(.8,.1))) # let's create a point and buffer it to have a polygon
pol = st_buffer(point,.1)
plot(pol, add = T)
r_masked = mask(r, as(pol, "Spatial"), inverse = T )

par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(r, axes = F, legend =F, bty = "n")
text(r)
plot(r_masked, axes = F, legend = F)
text(r_masked)
plot(pol, add = T)
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize there was an inverse=T option with mask! I'm excited to try this out! Thank you.